# How to Access Base project session from Outer dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created a web application and add one dll to it (XDav.Settings). In this dll under some condition, one event triggered and call one static action like this :

```
using NikDMSTools.Controllers;
using XDav.Settings;

namespace NikDMSTools
{
    public class XdavConfig 
    {

        public static void Register()
        {
            XDavSettings.Events(e =>
            {
                e.OnProcessing(evt =>
                {
                    if (evt.HttpVerp == XDav.Helper.HttpVerb.PUT)
                    {
                       DocumentController.xdav();
                    }
                })
               
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I call DocumentController.xdav().

```
public class DocumentController
    {
       public static void xdav()
       {     
         var userinfo = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserInfo"] as UserInfo;       
       }
    }
```

but sadlly System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session is null inside xdav function !!. How can i access session inside it ?

Answer (score 0):

You pass it to the function:

```
public class DocumentController
    {
       public static void xdav(System.Web.HttpContext context)
       {     
         var userinfo = context.Session["UserInfo"] as UserInfo;       
       }
    }
```

And call it like this at the place where the current context exists:

```
DocumentController.xdav(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
```

Comment: tnx Athanasios Kataras for reply. but problem is that dll sends its own httpcontext to static action !!! and dont recognize httpcontext of main project.